# Empty AssetsV2 folder in Finder

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, folders

I was doing some snooping around in the Finder on my mac and found that there is an empty folder titled "AssetsV2"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHz5B.png).
Im unsure of the direct path but it's found by selecting the following.
`Macintosh HD->System->Library`

The folder is completely empty when compared to the regular Assets folder next to it. Im unsure as to why i have a seconds assets folder if there's nothing inside of it. I did create both a volume partition and secondary volume from the Disk Utility app a few months ago and both were deleted since then.
Is "AssetsV2" just a ghost folder from either the partition or secondary volume i created?
Does anyone else have a secondary(or more) Assets folder as well?

Answer (score -2):

*Danger Will Robinson!*

Not sure why it matters that you have an empty folder in /System/Library but I have found from past experience that you **NEVER** touch anything in the /System folder. Doing so can lead to problems with your Mac up to and including making it non-bootable.

I completely ignore all folders outside of my home folder. Sure it is interesting to go exploring but honestly if it ain't broke don't fix it. And an empty folder takes up so little space on disk it's not worth deleting.

Comment: i understand where youre coming from to not touch anything in the folders under `/System/Library`, but my main question was to why there is a "AssetsV2" folder on my MacBook when my iMac displays only one? Thats why i was wondering if creating the disk partition or secondary volume created it, most likely the partition, but im unsure as to why its really there

Comment: Having done computer support for well over 20 years I have learned not to ask one question, "why?" Nine times out of ten you never find out and the 10th time you waste too much time finding out why, instead of just fixing the problem and moving on. Why is for programmers, after all they are the ones that created the folder in the first place.